# Question about eigenvalue of Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is an eigenvalue problem I found.

Let $A$ be an $n$-by-$n$ Hermitian complex matrix and $u$ is a vector in $C^n$ such that $u^*u=1$. Let $k=u^*Au$.

Show that there exists an eigenvalue $r$ of $A$ such that $|r-k| \le ||Au-ku||_2$ (norm-2).

I've been trying to use some facts about maximum or minimum eigenvalue but got no clue at the end. I think it talks about Rayleigh quotient tho.
How should it be done?

Comment: Sorry, the $*$ in $u^*u$ does NOT represent multiplication, right? It it just the product of $u^*$ and $u$?

Comment: @Rellek Yes it is just the product of $u$ conjugate and $u$.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Where did you find it? The best bound of this form I know about is $|r-k|\leq\|Au-ku\|_2^2/\delta$, where $\delta$ is the distance of $k$ to the nearest eigenvalue of $A$ different from $r$. Or if you remove the square from the norm, you get also a correct bound which however does not depend on how $k$ is computed.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Ah my bad. There shouldn't be any square. That's the only correction. Are you sure doesn't depend on how $k$ is computed? How did you do that? I thought I must include that $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to assume that $k$ is a Rayleigh quotient, the bound holds for any real $k$. If $A=VDV^*$ is a spectral decomposition of $A$ with a unitary $V$ and diagonal $D=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$, then 
$$
\|Au-ku\|_2=\|(A-kI)u\|_2=\|(D-kI)v\|_2,
$$
where $v=[\upsilon_1,\ldots,\upsilon_n]^T:=V^*u$, $\|v\|_2=\|u\|_2=1$. So
$$
\|Au-ku\|_2^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(\lambda_i-k)^2\upsilon_i^2\geq\min_{1\leq i\leq n}(\lambda_i-k)^2\sum_{i=1}^n\upsilon_i^2=\min_{1\leq i\leq n}(\lambda_i-k)^2.
$$